# How do I make a Two argument python function?

Tags: python, function

Is anyone able to help me on the below, I am struggling to understand what the question means by "where {person} is replaced by the first name in the visitors to be identified as a member." The below code is my attempt but I am not sure how to incorporate visitors into the function too...

```
members = ['Danny', 'Alex', 'Kieran', 'Zoe', 'Caroline']
visitors = ['Scott', 'Helen', 'Raj', 'Danny']

def check_group(members,visitors):
for m in members:
    if m == 'Danny':
        return f'Member present: {m}.'
    else:
        return 'No members.'

check_group(members, visitors)
```

Comment: When they say 'Member present: {person}`, they're presenting it as a template.  In reality, {person} would be some actual name, e.g. 'Member present: Fred', 'Member present: Mary' etc.  In other words, it should work for any name that's substituted for {person}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop over the visitors and then check if the visitor is a member. If you reach the end of the loop you haven't found any member and return "No members".

```
members = ['Danny', 'Alex', 'Kieran', 'Zoe', 'Caroline']
visitors = ['Scott', 'Helen', 'Raj', 'Danny']

def check_group(members, visitors):
    for visitor in visitors:
        if visitor in members::
            return f'Member present: {visitor}.'
    return 'No members.'

check_group(members, visitors)
```